# How to find the cause of slow performance in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I noticed my app becoming quite slow with increasing amounts of data.
I thought it is because of some filters in ng-repeats that are triggered too often, but I've optimized them already and there's still no sign of performance improvement.
Then I thought it's database slowness, but it turns out that wasn't the case either.

**I'd like to stop guessing where the slowness is coming from and find the cause systematically.**
**Does anyone know how to do this?**
I just see tons of optimizations articles everywhere, but first I want to find out what part of the code needs the optimization.

I ran this Chrome analysis - and it seems to me that there's some AngularJS functions that take forever, but I don't know how to find out what's causing them.
[image: Chrome Analysis Overview]
No idea how this can help me. Looks like there's a function call that takes 4.5 seconds...
I'd like to get rid of it :D :D
[image: Bottom-Up Slowest]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I was thinking too complicated...
I found the cause of the slowness simply by commenting everything out and commenting it in again step by step until the first slowness appeared :D